# ember-cli 0.0.40 version installation

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

```
 npm install ember-cli@0.0.40
```

returns E404.  I know that it is too old version, but i should work any way. Should I install anything else?  (0.0.44 works fine)
Any solution?

here is full output :

> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\
>   node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "ember-cli@0.0.40" npm
>   ERR! node v4.3.1 npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12 npm ERR! code E404
>
> npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/express s npm ERR! 404 npm ERR! 404
>   'expresss' is not in the npm registry. npm ERR! 404 You should bug the
>   author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
>
> npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'ember-cli' npm ERR!
>   404 npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a npm ERR! 404
>   tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log

here is npm version output:

> { npm: '2.14.12',   ares: '1.10.1-DEV',   http_parser: '2.5.2',   icu:
>   '56.1',   modules: '46',   node: '4.3.1',   openssl: '1.0.2f',   uv:
>   '1.8.0',   v8: '4.5.103.35',   zlib: '1.2.8' }

Answer (score 1):

You can download the package from the bottom of this page https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v0.0.40
Then you look up npm documentation on how to install from a file.

Comment: I tried it but still exception : 
npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@2.4.1: This package has been discontinued in favor of lodash@^4.0.0.
npm ERR! Darwin 15.2.0 ...
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'ember-cli'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

Comment: message from log : 1808 error 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/expresss

Comment: inside bin/package.json is wrong address of bundledDependencies : expresss